# How do I solve /dev/sda6 clean, ...?

Tags: boot, startup, disk, docker

I've been reading articles about this notification, but none of them helped. Also, before this problem occurred, I potentially misinstalled docker, and maybe that leads to this.

[image]

Comment: That is a notification not a problem.

Comment: Does your system boot normally after that? Or is it stuck for a while at that point?

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is an **informational** message, and it does not represent any issue on your system.  This is actually a good informational message to see since it means your system is in a 'clean' state on disk - no partition issues, readable filesystem currently, mounted up, and general stats on your disk size/usage of inodes and blocks.

This isn't an 'issue' that you fix, because if the system boots up properly after that then you're good to go and totally fine.

Comment: But, I am stuck at that point